# Azure webjob missing framework in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I just upgraded my webjob to .net core 7 using the NET Upgrade tool extension from Microsoft.  Everything runs fine locally but when I deploy to Azure, I am getting the following error.

> You must install or update .NET to run this application.
>
> App:
> C:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\Distributor-Integration-EMEA-Inbound\y13eysd3.sn5\DistributorIntegrationEMEA_Inbound_WebJob.exe
> Architecture: x64 Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version
> '7.0.0' (x64) .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet
>
> No frameworks were found.
>
> Learn about framework resolution:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
>
> To install missing framework, download:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

In Azure app service extensions, I installed the ASP.NET Core 7 runtime (x64) and that didn't make a difference.  I also saw in the error message that it mentions Microsoft.Windows.Desktop.App version 7 which I tried to install as a nuget package and I am getting an error for

> Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64 8.0.0' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project

What am I missing that is causing my webjob to not run in Azure but runs fine locally in VS 2022?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error when upgrading an Azure WebJob to .NET 6. After inspecting my project file I realized that I was targeting a specific OS:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

After updating this line to the following, re-building, and re-deploying it started as expected.

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: I tried making the same change, but the build fails for target OS.